# difference in the generated stdsoap.h with gsoap 2.8.10 and the later version from 2.8.11 & above

Tags: c, soap, wsdl, gsoap, onvif

We using gSOAP with ONVIF wsdl.  The responses with 2.8.10 is different from 2.8.11 & above version. This is what we are facing,

```
1. Installed 2.8.10 version.

2. Executed below command to generate header file for ONVIF event wsdl. 
wsdl2h -c -t /usr/local/share/gsoap/WS/typemap.dat -o event.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/event/wsdl/event.wsdl

3. soapcpp2 is invoked on header file (event.h) to generate both client and server side code.
soapcpp2 -c  -t -I /usr/local/share/gsoap/import/:/usr/local/share/gsoap event.h 

4. Respective structures will be generated in header file soapStub.h.
In soapStub.h look for structure, 
struct _ns1__GetEventPropertiesResponse->struct ns7__TopicSetType ->char **__any

*** Repeat step 2 & 3 with 2.8.11/12/13 installed and look for structures in soapStub.h struct _tev__GetEventPropertiesResponse->struct wstop__TopicSetType ->char *__any
```

Two changes are observed,

1. Regarding namespace. ns1 is replaced with tev.(Which has we solved it)
2. char __any is double pointer in 2.8.10 but in above versions, its is a single pointer. (Unable to solve this)

We are concerned about char __any.

Could you kindly help us understand why this difference seen in 2.8.11 & above versions. How do we overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

To change the xsd:any type to be a char ** put this line in your typemap file.

```
xsd__any = | char**
```